# helm says secret doesn't exist although it does

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Got a helm chart with an environment variable being imported from a kubernetes secret:

```
env:
  MONGO_URI:
   name: mongo-secret
   type: secret
   key: mongodb-uri
```

But when I try rendering the template, I get the following error:

```
error calling required: HELM_ERR_START
Attempted to reference unknown object mongo-secret. Either create it or add it to externalReferences HELM_ERR_END
```

But the secret exists:

```
$ kubectl get secrets

NAME                                                   TYPE                 DATA       AGE
mongo-secret                                           Opaque               1           1d
```

Am I missing something? How do I fix this error?

Comment: It's almost certain that the configured namespace in your current context is different from the namespace in which you're trying to install that helm release

Comment: That makes sense. How do I specify the namespace in my helm chart?

Comment: [`helm -n $my_namespace`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/#options) and it seems to honor `$HELM_NAMESPACE` if you don't want, or can't, provide extraneous args to `helm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the secret to `externalReferences` just as the error asked me to. Here is how I added it to the chart:

```
externalReferences:
  mongo-secret: 'mongo-secret'
```